# Converter String Json CSS Inline para um array ou json com PHP

Tags: php, json, array, return

tenho um cadastro no banco de dados em json e dentro do mesmo existe um objeto "style" no qual o mesmo possui um código de css inline, como por exemplo:

"padding: 90px 0px 20px 0px; background: #000000; display: block;"

Digamos que o retorno seria:

```
{
"style" : "padding: 90px 0px 20px 0px; background: #000000; display: block;"
}
```

E eu preciso pegar cada parâmetro e transformar em um array onde ficaria algo assim, gerando um array ou Json (não sei qual é a melhor solução), segue um exemplo do que quero:

```
{
"padding" : "90px 0px 20px 0px",
"background" : "#000000",
"display" : "block"
}
```

Pois vou pegar esse resultado e regar um input para cada chave, gerando um formulário para que o usuário consiga alterar os valores.

O mais perto que consegui chegar foi com isso:

```
$wrapStyle = "padding: 90px 0px 20px 0px; background: #000000; display: block;";
$bringStyleString = array_filter(explode(";", json_encode($wrapStyle)));
$bringStyleString = array_filter(explode(";", json_encode($wrapStyle)));
$br = json_decode(json_encode(array_filter(explode(";",$wrapStyle))));
$tks = array();

foreach ($br as $key => $value) {

    $t = explode(":", $value);
    $tk = $t[1];

    $tk1 = array(trim($t[0]));
    $tk2 = array(trim($t[1]));

    $tk = json_decode(json_encode($tk));
    $tks[] = array_combine($tk1, $tk2);

}

$contagem = count($tks);

print_r($tks);
```

Esta gerando um array e dentro dele outros arrays, gostaria de deixar todos os retornos dentro de um array apenas como por exemplo sendo esse o retorno:

Array ( [padding] => 90px 0px 20px 0px, [background] => #000000, [display] => block )

Seria esse o caminho? Ou melhor seguir outro totalmente diferente?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar `array_reduce` para gerar ele de uma só vez, segue um exemplo

```
$wrapStyle = "padding: 90px 0px 20px 0px; background: #000000; display: block;";

$explode = explode(';',$wrapStyle);

$styles = array_reduce($explode,function($carry,$item){
    if(empty($item))return $carry;
    $itemExplode = explode(':',$item);
    if(empty($itemExplode[0]) || empty($itemExplode[1]))return $carry;
    $carry[$itemExplode[0]] = $itemExplode[1];
    return $carry;
},[]);

echo json_encode($styles); //{"padding":" 90px 0px 20px 0px"," background":" #000000"," display":" block"}
```

Comment: Poxa Antonio, muito obrigado.... pegando o resultado via ajax eu consigo fazer exatamente o que preciso fazer. Confesso que estou faz um tempinho quebrando a cabeça com isso, hoje agradeço pela ajuda.